# delete several related rows from diffrent tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a db like this

```
table 1 : area
+------------+
| id | name  |
+------------+
| 1  | area1 |
+------------+

table 2 : area_members
+------------------------+
| rel_area  | rel_school |
+------------------------+

table 3 : school
+------------+
| id  | name |
+------------+

table 4 : school_members
+---------------------------+
| rel_school  | rel_student |
+---------------------------+

table 5 : student
+------------+
| id  | name |
+------------+
```

In this table any area has several schools and any school has several students.
I want to delete anythings which related to 'area1' (area , schools , students ) from all of these 5 tables by deleting area1 .

I have tried some JOIN and UNION queries but I couldn't fix it .
can any one help me , please ?
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply join the tables and the best part is, MySQL allows you to delete multiple tables in just one query.

```
DELETE  a, b, c, d, e
FROM    area a
        INNER JOIN are_members b
            ON a.ID = b.rel_area
        INNER JOIN school c
            ON b.rel_school = c.ID
        INNER JOIN school_members d
            ON c.ID = d.rel_school
        INNER JOIN student e
            ON d.rel_student = e.ID
WHERE   a.Name = 'area1'
```

*PS: please **backup your database** before executing the statement above*

Comment: it works ,thanks a milion
but I couldn't understand why did you use a,b,c,d,e
it seems kind of table rename , am I true ?

Comment: this is not the basic delete statement, when you have join the tables in your delete statement, you should specify where the records should be deleted. `a,b,c,d,e` are the alias given for each table.

Comment: oh, I've got it.
excuse me, but I have one more question
I tried this query but it doesn't work when any of related tables doesn't have related rows
for example when an area doesn't have any student this query delete nothing

:(

Comment: you didn't say so, try I'm not sure if changing `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` works. try it but first backup the database.

Answer (score 0):

when defining foreign key constraint you can specify whether deleted record affect other records that is related to it with the foreign key
there is an option you can specify when declaring the foreign key : **on delete cascade**.
suppose table **B** belong to table **A** . if you specify **on delete cascade** : this will cause records in table **B** to be deleted if they are related to record in table **A**, when this record in table **A** is deleted